# How To Assign Value On Each Element In Array?

Tags: php, arrays

So, basically I have this array data:

```
$data = ['one', 'two', 'three'];
```

Now, I want to assign a value on each element on that array, that would be something like this:

```
$val = 'new';

// 'new' value is get from $val
$data = [
 'one' => 'new',
 'two' => 'new',
 'three' => 'new'
];
```

How did I do that? Thanks.

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava - that is more for an array with `'one' => 'one',`

Answer (score 1):

```php
$data = ['one', 'two', 'three'];
$val = 'new';
$newArray = array_fill_keys($data, $val);
print_r($newArray);
```

Fiddle [here](https://3v4l.org/ej7Nk).